# Could Someone Provide a Broken down Description for the Vim Command gqip?

Tags: vim, neovim

My understanding is that the command `gqip`, when in normal mode, tells vim to format the current paragraph, separated by whitespace, using the `formatoptions` as rules. But I can't find any information on the command itself to see other possible use-cases like it. More specifically, what I would like to know is if you break up the command `gqip` into `g`, `q`, `i`, and `p`, what do these individual components do to give the command its behaviour?

Comment: I recommend using `gw` instead of `gq` because it keeps your cursor position

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`gq{motion}` (`:help gq`) Formats the lines covered by `{motion}`.

A motion can generally be any command that would move the cursor, in which case it covers everything between the initial and final cursor positions, or a "text object".

`:help text-objects` lists all the text objects, specifically:

> ip            "inner paragraph", select [count] paragraphs (see
> |paragraph|).
> Exception: a blank line (only containing white space)
> is also a paragraph boundary.
> When used in Visual mode it is made linewise.

Answer (score 4):

This question illustrates one of the biggest problems of relying on random, disconnected, pieces of information gathered from random sources instead of learning Vim properly.

`gqip` is really `gq`, an operator, and `ip`, a motion.

The concepts of "operator" and "motion" are introduced in lesson 2 of `$ vimtutor` and further discussed in chapter 4 of the user manual: `:help 04.1`, while the concept of text object is introduced a little further in the same chapter: `:help 04.8`.

Learning Vim is not even "like" learning a language, it *is* learning a language and the user manual is structured in a way that follows common language teaching techniques: in the beginning, the user is given a handful of basic commands ( "delete", "yank", "to next word", etc., a *vocabulary*) and shown how to compose them (a *grammar*) to affect the text in a file. The idea is to start simple and gradually introduce more vocabulary and more grammar rules.

Once the user has internalised *some* vocabulary and *some* grammar, they can acquire new commands easily and immediately compose them with previously acquired ones in more complex "sentences", just like a language learner.

And, FWIW, here is the whole `:help 10.7`, which happens to cover `gqap`, which is easy to extrapolate to any `gq` + motion, thanks to what you learned *earlier*, in chapter 4:

> *10.7*    Formatting text
>
> When you are typing plain text, it's nice if the length of each line is
> automatically trimmed to fit in the window.  To make this happen while
> inserting text, set the 'textwidth' option:
>
> ```
> :set textwidth=72
> ```
>
> You might remember that in the example vimrc file this command was used for
> every text file.  Thus if you are using that vimrc file, you were already
> using it.  To check the current value of 'textwidth':
>
> ```
> :set textwidth
> ```
>
> Now lines will be broken to take only up to 72 characters.  But when you
> insert text halfway through a line, or when you delete a few words, the lines
> will get too long or too short.  Vim doesn't automatically reformat the text. To tell Vim to format the current paragraph:
>
> ```
> gqap
> ```
>
> This starts with the "gq" command, which is an operator.  Following is "ap",
> the text object that stands for "a paragraph".  A paragraph is separated from
> the next paragraph by an empty line.
>
> Note:
> A blank line, which contains white space, does NOT separate
> paragraphs.  This is hard to notice!
>
> Instead of "ap" you could use any motion or text object.  If your paragraphs
> are properly separated, you can use this command to format the whole file:
>
> ```
> gggqG
> ```
>
> "gg" takes you to the first line, "gq" is the format operator and "G" the
> motion that jumps to the last line.
>
> In case your paragraphs aren't clearly defined, you can format just the lines
> you manually select.  Move the cursor to the first line you want to format.
> Start with the command "gqj".  This formats the current line and the one below
> it.  If the first line was short, words from the next line will be appended.
> If it was too long, words will be moved to the next line.  The cursor moves to
> the second line.  Now you can use "." to repeat the command.  Keep doing this
> until you are at the end of the text you want to format.

With the foundational knowledge provided by `:help user-manual`, `gqip` can't be a mystery.

Comment: None of these sources cover the function of "i" in `gqip`.  That use of "i" is difficult to search for: `i` means something different, and `help gqi` or `help gqip`, etc. returns no help.  One needs `:help text-objects`, as @OhleC indicates.

Comment: There is no "i" in `gqip` so there is no reason to expect it to be covered anywhere. `gqip` is `gq` followed by `ip` and, again, there is absolutely no mystery to it if you follow the manual properly. If you don't, then you are bound to waste your time with silly notions like the one you exhibited in your comment or OP exhibited in their question. The knowledge and understanding is there: easy to find, easy to follow, and free for all.

Comment: Thanks @romaini.  I agree with your point about lots of other information in the vim help system.  I think we can agree to disagree about this particular bit of information.